# magento 1 'Stop Further Rules Processing' setting acting strange

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules

I added a cart rule with 10% of product price discount to all products. I selected 'Yes' for **Stop Further Rules Processing** drop-down, but its not giving 10% discount, instead it gives almost a 1% discount.

When i set **Stop Further Rules Processing** to 'NO' then i get the correct discount.

Is there any other setting which is effecting the discount value ?

Answer (score 0):

The Stop further rules processing flag allows you to make relationships between different rules. Your store will execute the shopping cart rules  in order of priority. IF the system reaches a rule with the Stop Further Rules Processing flag it will stop going through any lower priority rules. This allows you to make some rules exclusive.

For example, you can make a discount coupon with  priority value of "10" and a daily discount of priority "5". The coupon gives you $10-off. If the coupon is not used, the cart gives $5 off. If the coupon is used, now the cart is giving $15-off.

If you want to disable the regular discount when the coupon is used you can set the coupon to have the "Stop Further Rule Processing" option to YES. This will keep the $5-off rule when the customer is not using the coupon. If the customer does uses the coupon code, it will disable the $5-off rule and only do the coupon action. The result is a $10-off discount instead of the undesired combined $15-off discount.

Comment: thanks for the explanation but why my rule is not working 'when Stop Further Rules Processing' is set to YES.

Comment: have you cleared cache..?

Comment: yes also done re-indexing, it works when its set to 'No'.